# Using amCharts together with vue.js for a dynamic list with v-for

Tags: vue.js, amcharts, foalts

I am actually building a SPA with foalts.org.
I have placed my script.js inside the public folder. Unfortunately, this doesn't allow me to use typescript for my vue-js. Maybe someone has an idea for this, cause actually the public folder got served from foalTS framework. But this is actually not the main topic.

The maintopic is, that i want to list several divs with

```
<div class="row-position" v-for="order in orders" :key="order.latestPrice">
  <div id="myAMchart></div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to be able to place an amChart (https://www.amcharts.com/) for each div. And I want that these charts follow the value of order.latestPrice. But I actually have no idea how to set up this with amCharts and vue.js

Im open to any ideas.

I was able to update one single chart but with a fixed id of the div.
I don't know how to connect the many different (dynamicaly generated) charts to the order.latestPrice field.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably create a AmChartComponent, which handles the logic for each order

Comment: Hi Mick. Thank you for your comment. im quite new to node.js and also to foalTS. I assume that you propose to write an component TypeScript?. But anyway... i dont see how to connect the single <div id="amChart"></div> to some logic... how can i connect such a chart to an order position?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the AmCharts Vue page https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-vue-js/

Comment: Thanks. I have already done that. In fact, they do all the code inside of   mounted(). I have also done the same right now. But this only shows how to initialize amChart after full rendering. There are no information about linking charts from inside a list....

Comment: Start by making it work with a single chart. Put this logic inside a Vue component and it should be straight forward making it work with multiple charts.

Comment: ok, it is working with a single chart right now. Ok, i will take a look at how to create components... thanks